# Converting list of entity class objects to JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, rdd

I have a list of objects of Person class. I want to convert it into JavaPairRDD.

---

I want to create pairs of Object,BSONObject type so as to store these in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what pairs you want to get from a single Person object, but this code should be a good start. Anyway I advice you to read some examples:
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf());
JavaPairRdd<Object, BSONObject> rdd = ctx
  .parallelize(list)
  .mapToPair(person -> new Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>(person, convertToBson(person));

public BSONObject convertToBson(final Person person) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am using SparkContext and not JavaSparkContext. 

Also, the pairs I want to create is of <Object,BSONObject>.  I want to save this data into MongoDB.

Comment: But you're writing in Java right? You should use JavaSparkContext as far as I am concerned.